# Box - Cox transformation and inconsistent results between different packages

Tags: r, math, statistics, tidyverse, linear-regression

could you tell me please what is the difference between Box-Cox transformation via `MASS` and `Car` packages (given below)? Because I get different results:

```
library(car)
x <- runif(110)
lambda <- coef(powerTransform(1/x))


library(MASS)

b <- boxcox(lm(x ~ 1))
# Exact lambda
lambda <- b$x[which.max(x)]
```

Answer (score 0):

The code for your "exact lambda" is not correct:

```
set.seed(666L)
x <- runif(100)

car::powerTransform(x)
# 0.7231341 
b <- MASS::boxcox(x ~ 1, lambda = seq(-2, 2, 1/100))
b$x[which.max(b$y)]
# 0.72
```